# Split the set of real numbers into $2$-element sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

How can we split $\mathbb{R}$ into **disjoint** sets, each consisting of $2$ elements?

I have found a similar (though much more general) question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/382965/131263).

But I am unable to deduce an answer to my specific question.

---

When taking the naive approach of $\{(x,-x)|x\in\mathbb{R^+}\}$ we exclude $0$.

Intuitively, I have concluded that $\mathbb{R}$ has an "odd" number of elements.

This leads me to think that splitting $\mathbb{R}$ into $2$-element sets is not feasible.

I do realize, however, that we cannot refer to an infinite number as odd or even.

Comment: You can break $\mathbb{Z}$ into $...\{-4, -3\}, \{-2, -1\}, \{0, 1\}, \{2, 3\}, ...$, and non-integers into $\{-x, x\}$.

Comment: If $x$ is not an integer, partners are $x$ and $-x$, as you suggested. If $x$ is an integer, $x$ and $1-x$ can be partners.

Comment: @lisyarus: $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a problem. In fact, any countable set is not much of a problem, because you can easily "biject" it to $\mathbb{Z}$. My problem is with uncountable sets, such as $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @barakmanos: lisyarus's answer is for $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: OK, I understand that now (from the answer below to be honest).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First consider the pairs $(2n,2n+1)$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$. Then consider the pairs $(-x,x)$ for $x\notin\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

$\{(x,a-x)\mid x\in\mathbb{R^+}, a=1$ if $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ else $a=0\}$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that doesn't treat the integers as special:

Use sets of the form $\{x,x+1 \mid x\in [2n,2n+1), n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

The idea is to partition the real line by means of half open unit intervals, and pair corresponding elements of neighboring intervals.  So for instance elements of $[-2,-1)$ pair with elements of $[-1,0)$; elements of $[0,1)$ pair with elements of $[1,2)$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For negative numbers, just use the pairs $(x,\frac{1}{x})$. For nonnegative numbers, proceed as follows. To make binary representation of real numbers unique, always replace an infinite tail like $0.111\ldots$ by $1.0$, etc. Then pair up numbers that differ only in the first decimal place with respect to this unique representation.  Thus, $0.0$ will pair up with $0.1$, while $1.1011\ldots$ will pair up with $1.0011\ldots$, etc.

Comment: This description is not very clear to me.