# Define a bijection such that $f(x)\neq x$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ a set such that $|A|>1$. Iwant to prove that there exists a bijection $f:A\rightarrow A$ such that $f(x)\neq x$.

First, by AC, I can obtain a well order for $A$, and w.l.o.g I suppose that it has order type $\alpha$. So $A=\{x_\xi\}_{\xi<\alpha}$. Now, define the set $C_\xi=A\setminus\{x_\xi\}$. By transfinite recursion I can define the element $y_\xi=\min C_\xi\setminus\{y_\beta:\beta<\xi\}$.

Then, the function $f:A\rightarrow A$ such that $f(x_\xi)=y_\xi$ is the desire function.

Is it fine my approach?

Comment: How do you prove that $C_\xi \setminus \{y_\beta : \beta<\xi\} \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: @Federico Fine, this construction works if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, right?

Comment: Well, intuitively I would say that it always works, but I don't see immediately why the set is non-empty

Comment: The axiom of choice tag is meant for questions where you're asking specifically about the *necessity* of choice in the proof. Not for questions whose answers use choice (since that would encompass a significant portion of this site).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Well maybe it's interesting to know if this problem requires AC

Comment: @Federico: Of course it does, but that would be a duplicate of at least two questions.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Which ones? I cannot find them

Comment: You should mention "bijection" in the body of the question, not just in the title (without that it's a triviality).

Comment: @Federico: For example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134152/prove-that-every-set-with-more-than-one-element-has-a-permutation-without-fixed

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do the following.

If $A$ is finite but not a singleton, then it's simple: just cycle the elements.

If $A$ is infinite, show that $A=A_1 \sqcup A_2$ with $|A_1|=|A_2|$ and take any bijection $\phi:A_1\to A_2$. Then $f|_{A_1}=\phi$ and $f|_{A_2}=\phi^{-1}$ is a solution.

Comment: $A$ can't be a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the fact that every infinite set $X$ can be partitioned into blocks of size 2  using ordinal theory; see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/382987/432081). So we partition $X$

$\tag 1 X = \cup \; F_\lambda \text{ with #}(F_\lambda) = 2$

Once you have that you are in business. Set

$\tag 2 F_{(\lambda, \rho)} = (F_\lambda \times F_\lambda) \setminus \{(x,x) \, | \, x \in F_\lambda\}$

The union of the $F_{(\lambda, \rho)}$ is a bijective correspondence $f$ with $f(x) \ne x$. It can be viewed as a union of transpositions.